# How to style a custom rounded underline in a Angular Material Tab

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

Our designers want us to implement underlines to look like this:

[image: Desired underline style]

It's essentially the top half of a rectangle with rounded corners. However, we're using Angular Material and I'm not having any luck styling the existing component (https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/examples)

I was able to make the default underline thicker with rounded corners by setting these to variables:

`--mdc-tab-indicator-active-indicator-height: 6px;`

`--mdc-tab-indicator-active-indicator-shape: 10px;`

This is what I currently have:
[image: Current underline style]

I'm not even sure how to search for what I'm trying to do here. Any tips are appreciated before I skip using the Material component and building something myself.

Comment: Did you try border-top-left-radius and border-top-right-radius? Pls share a stackblitz if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Thuan mentioned, below is the CSS to do it, with a working example!

```
.mdc-tab-indicator .mdc-tab-indicator__content {
  color: #a31b56 !important;
  border-color: #a31b56 !important;
  border-top-width: 7px !important;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px !important;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px !important;
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/usv9a6?file=src%2Fstyles.scss,src%2Fexample%2Ftab-group-basic-example.html)

Comment: Thank you, my friends. I was just having trouble finding the right place to modify the CSS.